# human readable url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have such .htaccess in my root folder of website:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

Options -indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

This is created by some CMS which is installed.

I have a folder named, for example, `test` in root folder. 
The questions are:

- How can I remove this folder from global (root htaccess) rewrite rule
- This folder has it's own htaccess. What to add there to allow me doing like this:

> ```
>    site.com/test/some-data
>    --->
>    site.com/test/?id=some-data
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you may try this in the .htaccess file in root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !test           [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)           index.php       [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/? /test/?id=$1   [L,NC]
```

There is no need for another .htaccess file in `/test` directory. Use only this one.

Comment: It partly works, but something is wrong with loading of css, for example. The urls are also rewritten like: `site.com/test/css/main.css` and everything becomes broken :(

Comment: You mean in the root .htaccess, that is not skipping the rule when the `/test` folder is present?

Comment: Oh :( Even first htaccess for root does the same as I described in first comment

Comment: Modified my answer for only one .htaccess file at root directory.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I'll test it in a few hours and than report here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a separate .htaccess in your test directory, this one should be sufficient

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.
RewriteRule .+ ?id=$0
```